# PHP - Using Sessions to temporarily save variables for ajax application

Tags: php, ajax, session

I wonder if the following would be a good Idea or rather contra-productive performance-wise:

An Ajax-Application, like for example a pagebrowser needs some language- and config-values, which are stored in the database. So each time, the user is using this app, in the ajax-script the mysql-query to get the variables is done again and again. concidering this for a pagebrowser, there might be like 10 or more requests (back and forward, back, forward, and so on), aka 10 x database-select, while it is needed only one time actually.

My idea was, to safe the config-vars in a session-array the first time, the ajax-app is requested. If the sessions-array exists, the mysql-query isnt done again. 
if the user calls another regular page, these session-array is deleted again.

Now im not really sure, what would consume more server-resources, using sessions in the above described way for saving the vars teporarily, or just using a mysql-query to get the vars each time, the user klicks the ajax-app.

Thanx in advance, Jayden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet sessions would be more effective, but the best way is to test and measure the different execution times.

Comment: okay, thanks, gonna check this as the accepted answer, as it matches the question, even when not very certain and more like a guess. maybe i gonna benchmark this somehow, would have to think about, how to do that. would you stick to your opinion, that sessions would be more effective, even if the session would contain, lets say, like 30 keys? thanks, jayden

Answer (score 2):

If you working with massive amount of data, you could consider using Cookies as well instead of session for server resources, which will be stored in the user's local browser.

Comment: Sure, if you see how the session works, its actually stores a session id cookie in the browser and every-time the session id is used in the request communication. So it would not be harm to use the cookies instead of sessions, since the total process is somewhat reduced. Because I have used cookies specially for storing user preferences settings for UI and some other stuffs. Also if you use cookies, you'll have the flexibility to access the cookie values with both server side and javascript as well.

Comment: Though cookies are sent with every http request, so any requests not using the cookies will be slowed down if you use bigger ammounts of data.